# MediaWiki to Plain text Conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion, converters, mediawiki, wiki

I am having a Text as shown below.I am confused that it is a media wiki text or wiki text or any other.I want to convert it into simple plain text without any loss of data.Can Someone suggest any Site,API or anything similar to that for conversion :

```
        "<div id="yellowbox">
    '''[[ANG TP|Title Page]]''' 

    '''[[ANG CP|Confidentiality Page]]''' 

    '''[[ANG DRN|Document Release Notice]]''' 

    '''[[ANG RH|Document Revision List]]''' 

    '''[[ANG ABT|About This Manual]]''' 

    '''[[GL_Abbreviation|List of Abbreviations]]'''

    '''[[ANG 1|SECTION 1]]''' '''REQUIREMENTS ANALYSIS PHASE''' 

    :1.1 The Activities

    :1.2 Deciding Areas of Automation

    :1.3 General Tips

    '''SECTION 2 ANALYSIS ACTIVITIES''' 

    :[[ANG 2.1|2.1]] Defining User Requirements

    :[[ANG 2.2|2.2]] Performing Problem Diagnosis

    :[[ANG 2.3|2.3]] Generating Alternative Solutions

    :[[ANG 2.4|2.4]] Performing Impact Analysis

    :[[ANG 2.5|2.5]] Selection of Solution

    :[[ANG 2.6|2.6]] Defining Software Requirements

    '''[[ANG 3|SECTION 3]]''' '''MODELING''' 

    :3.1 Types of Models

    ::3.1.1 Process Modeling

    ::3.1.2 Data Modeling

    ::3.1.3 Object Modeling

    ::3.1.4 A Word of Caution

    :3.2 Techniques and Tools

    ::3.2.1 Process Modeling

    ::3.2.2 Data Modeling

    ::3.2.3 Object Modeling

    :3.3 Conventions

    ::3.3.1 Process Modeling

    ::3.3.2 Data Modeling

    ::3.3.3 Object Modeling

    '''[[ANG 4|SECTION 4]]''' '''DOCUMENTATION FRAMEWORK''' 

    :4.1 The User Requirements Specification

    ::[[ANG 4.1.1|4.1.1]] Format of URS

    ::[[ANG 4.1.2|4.1.2]] Contents of URS

    :[[ANG 4.2|4.2]] The Alternatives and Impacts Document

    ::[[ANG 4.2.1|4.2.1]] Format of AID

    ::[[ANG 4.2.2|4.2.2]] Contents of AID

    :[[ANG 4.3|4.3]] The Software Requirements Specifications

    ::[[ANG 4.3.1|4.3.1]] Format of SRS

    ::[[ANG 4.3.2|4.3.2]] Contents of SRS

    :::SRS Section 1 Introduction

    ::::1.1 Purpose

    ::::1.2 Scope

    ::::1.3 Definitions, acronyms and abbreviations

    ::::1.4 References

    ::::1.5 Overview

    :::SRS Section 2 General Requirements

    ::::2.1 Product perspective

    :::::2.1.1 System interfaces

    :::::2.1.2 User interfaces

    :::::2.1.3 Hardware interfaces

    :::::2.1.4 Software interfaces

    :::::2.1.5 Communications interfaces

    :::::2.1.6 Memory constraints

    :::::2.1.7 Operations

    :::::2.1.8 Site adaptation requirements

    ::::2.2 Product functions

    ::::2.3 User characteristics

    ::::2.4 Constraints

    ::::2.5 Assumptions and dependencies

    ::::2.6 Apportioning of the requirements

    :::SRS Section 3 Specific requirements

    ::::3.1 External interfaces

    ::::3.2 Functions

    ::::3.3 Performance requirements

    ::::3.4 Logical database requirements

    ::::3.5 Design constraints

    ::::3.6 Standards compliance

    ::::3.7 Software system attributes

    :::::3.7.1 Reliability

    :::::3.7.2 Availability

    :::::3.7.3 Security

    :::::3.7.4 Maintainability

    :::::3.7.5 Portability

    ::::3.8 Organizing the specific requirements

    :::::3.8.1 System mode

    :::::3.8.2 User class

    :::::3.8.3 Objects

    :::::3.8.4 Feature

    :::::3.8.5 Stimulus

    :::::3.8.6 Response

    :::::3.8.7 Functional hierarchy

    ::::3.9 Additional comments

    '''[[ANG 5|SECTION 5]]''' '''PROTOTYPING''' 

    :5.1 Throwaway Prototyping

    :5.2 Evolutionary Prototyping

    :5.3 Comparison

    :5.4 Tools

    '''[[ANG 6|SECTION 6]]''' '''INFORMATION GATHERING''' 

    :6.1 Initial Information

    :6.2 Workshops and Interviews

    :6.3 Verification and Validation

    :6.4 What to ask

    '''[[ANG A|APPENDIX A]] EXAMPLE DOCUMENTATION''' 

    '''[[ANG B|APPENDIX B]]''' '''SRS TEMPLATES''' 

    '''[[ANG C|APPENDIX C]]''' '''LIST OF PROBLEMS''' 

    '''[[ANG D|APPENDIX D]]''' '''REQUIREMENTS ENGINEERING REFERENCES''' 

    '''[[ANG E|APPENDIX E]]''' '''MODELING AND METHODOLOGY REFERENCES''' 

    '''[[ANG F|APPENDIX F]]''' '''ADDITIONAL TOOLS FOR MODELING''' 

    '''[[ANG G|APPENDIX G]]''' '''REQUIREMENTS ANALYSIS FORMS''' 

    '''[[ANG H|APPENDIX H]]''' '''MODELING SYMBOLS''' 

    '''[[ANG I|APPENDIX I]]''' '''ORGANISATIONAL ISSUES''' 

    '''[[ANG J|APPENDIX J]]''' '''TEMPLATES FOR SRS''' 

    '''[[ANG GY|GLOSSARY]]''' 

    '''[[Media:Org_it_(TCS-iQMS-051)_QF1020.doc|Feedback Form]]'''
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="box">
    Service Line:[[Service Line::IT_Services]] 

    Page Name: [[Name::Index Page]] 

    Applicable For: 

    *[[Applicable for::Development]] 

    *[[Applicable for::Maintenance]]

    *[[Applicable for::Conversion]] 

    *[[Applicable for::Package_Implementation]] 

    *[[Applicable for::Re_-_Engineering]] 

    *[[Applicable for::CAD]] 

    *[[Applicable for::SAP-CCC]] 

    *[[Applicable for::FEA]] 

    *[[Applicable for::Infrastructure_Internal]] 

    Section of: [[Section of::Analysis_Guidelines]]

    Summary:  

    * [[Summary::This guidelines provide methods of preparing SRS for both OOAD and traditional SSAD methods used for Systems Analysis]]
    </div>

    [[Category:Guidelines]]"
```

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by "without any loss of data". Plain text format does not generally support things like hyperlinks, so how would you represent that concept in plain text without a loss of information?

Comment: With "Loss of Data" i mean that i want to convert above text to a plain text in such a way that no data gets misseed out.

Comment: yes which is why you need to say how exactly you intend to convert hyperlinks. For example "2.1 Defining User Requirements" is plain text of part of your text, but "2.1" should be a hyperlink to a page called `ANG 2.1`. How is this information supposed to be formatted as plain text?

Comment: That what for only i have asked this question.

Comment: Then basically you're out of luck, as plain text doesnt have any inherent hyperlink support, and MediaWiki does have support for hyperlinks, so converting to plain text must necessarily involve some loss of information, unless you're able to define "loss of information" in such a way that it is feasible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want a plain text representation of this, which will remove all hyperlinking functionality etc., then I guess the easiest manual solution would be to use an existing wiki. You can just edit any page, paste your code in, press preview (don’t save please!) and then you get the parsed representation of the wiki text. You can then copy paste that and paste it into a text editor.

Otherwise, if you don’t want to lose any formatting, then you could either copy the resulting HTML, or just keep the wiki text as it is. This makes especially sense if there are more complicated structures within, e.g. tables or template calls.